# I have limit of 12 items, but dynamodb query always returns 10 only

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using [dynamodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb) npm to query `dynamodb`

When I query as below, though I set **limit as 12 items**, It always returns **10 items**

```
TableDB
  .query(lang)
  .filter('users').in(['case1','case2'])
  .attributes(['offerId', 'lang'])
  .ascending()
  .usingIndex('lang-date-index')
  .limit(12)
  .exec((err, data) => {
    console.log(data)
  }
```

I don't want to query again using `lastEvaluateKey` just for next 2 items.

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: You sure the data had more than 10 items?

Comment: Yes, definitely.

Comment: What about if you try using limit less than 10? It will return correct amount? If so. Maybe you have in server settings limit to return results of 10 max? If limit < 10 will not work than it's problem with limit method in module itself. Hope this will helps.

Comment: After debugging come to know if I remove `.filter` it gives 12 results,
If I apply `.filter` it gives 10 results with `lastEvaluateKey`(means it has more results). @Mykola It works if I have less than 5 results

Comment: Maybe this will provide some info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40138551/how-can-i-do-dynamodb-limit-after-filtering

Comment: Thanks @MykolaBorysyuk for link, I guess I need to reiterate for next page.

Comment: Try `.loadAll()` before `exec()`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Dynamo applies limit first and only then filters. See [Scan limit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.Limit).
This means, if your table has 3 items in the order below :

```
Dog1
Cat1
Dog2
```

You filter by dogs and your read limit is 2 then you get following result set:

```
Dog1
```

The dynamo response will also provide *LastEvaluatedKay* which is the last read primary key on your table. Set this *LastEvaluatedKay* as *ExclusiveStartKey* in your next results. Here's a similar [example of pagination loop for dynamo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47748513/pagination-in-dynamo-db-while-scan-operation/47768751#47768751)  (in java).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
.loadAll()
```

The docs aren't too clear on what this does, but it sounds promising.